# GWT EditorDriver Proxy Object Modification

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

This is an edited version of a question that I had previously asked (and that tbroyer answered) about why the `isDirty()` method didn't return `true` after attempting to modify the `Editor` version of an entity. I think that my understanding of the `RequestFactory`/`EditorDriver` handling of entities is the issue, and that the `isDirty()` question was a red herring. I've left my original question at the end of this question, but my new question is:

How can the entity (proxy) that is being edited by an `EditorDriver` be modified in code? Obviously values will be changed as a result of changes in the user interface; but I don't know how to change values 'behind the scenes'. My understanding is that the call to `EditorDriver.edit()` will create a copy of the proxy object, and that subsequently any changes to that copy will be applied to the original object using `EditorDriver.flush()`. But `EditorDriver.edit()` does not return a reference to the object that is being edited (unlike `RequestContext.edit()`, which does return a reference to the object being edited).

The original (ill-informed) question:

I don't understand why the EditorDriver.isDirty() method is not returning true in the following situation (the following onOrgSelectedEvent() method is invoked when a new Org has been selected from a listbox):

```
private IOrgProxy _org;
...
/**
 * Loads the currently selected Org into the editor. 
 */
@Override
public void onOrgSelectedEvent(final OrgSelectedEvent orgSelectedEvent) {
  IOrgProxy org = _clientFactory.getCache().getOrgCache().getOrg(orgSelectedEvent.getOrgId());
  _orgRequestContext = _clientFactory.getRequestFactory().newOrgRequestContext();
  _org = _orgRequestContext.edit(org);
  _orgEditorDriver.edit(_org, _orgRequestContext);
  _org.setName(_org.getName() + " (edit)");
  if (_orgEditorDriver.isDirty()) {
    _org.setName(org.getName());
  }
}
```

When I put breakpoints on the setName() calls I see that the first call changes the name in the editable Org object, but the second setName() call is never reached (i.e., _orgEditorDriver.isDirty() returns false).

Just as a side question, it seems strange to me that the EditorDriver.edit() method doesn't return the editable proxy object, and that I have to call RequestContext.edit(), but that's a very minor issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would `isDirty` be true just after `edit`? Clearly the user hasn't be given the time to do any change.

`isDirty` compares the current value of the subeditors to their original value, it doesn't care whether the object changed: if you lend the object to the editor, you implicitly gives it control over the edited object (for the edited properties).

Comment: So does the call to `RequestContext.edit()` create a copy of the proxy object? And the call to `EditorDriver.edit()` create another copy? If so, I don't need the call to `RequestContext.edit()`; but how can I modify the object that the Editor owns?

Comment: `RequestContext.edit()` creates a copy of the proxy. `RequestFactoryEditorDriver.edit()` calls `RequestContext.edit()`, which *won't* create yet a new object: there's only one editable proxy instance in a `RequestContext` for a given `stableId()`. Between `edit()` and `flush()`, a property should only be changed through its `Editor`; if there's no `Editor` for the proprety, then you're free to change it independently of the `EditorDriver` "edit cycle".

Comment: Many thanks, Thomas ... I really appreciate your help, and your blog posts, and I think I understand now: if I change the value of the "name" attribute then I need to do this using `name.setText()` (`name` is the field on the screen); I can't change it using `_org.setName()`.

Comment: However, I still have an issue if I want to, for example, mark any record that has been viewed, regardless of whether the user actually changed a value. If I have columns in the database that represent "ViewDate" and "ViewUserId", then I would introduce these into the entity; but there will be no `Editor` for these fields, and the values will be changed behind the scenes; but `isDirty()` will return `false`, I think, and so I would need another way to know that the entity needs to be flushed and fired (sent back to the server).

Comment: Should I use `RequestContext.isChanged()` instead of `EditorDriver.isDirty()`?

Comment: Either `RequestContext.isChanged()` or use a [`SimpleEditor`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/adapters/SimpleEditor.html)